# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. while using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting an error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

My Hook Code:

```
function WidthAndHeight() {
  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(window.innerWidth);
  const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(window.innerHeight);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateWidthAndHeight);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateWidthAndHeight);
  });

  const updateWidthAndHeight = () => {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    setHeight(window.innerHeight);
  };

  return (
    {
      "width": width,
      "height": height
    }
  );
}
```

When I call it on `onMouseEnter` it gives the error below:

```
class MegaMenu extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.MegaMenu}>
        <div className={styles["menu-container"]}>
          <div className={styles.menu}>
            <MenuList Options={menus} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const MenuList = (props: IMenuListProps) => {
  const handleOnMouseEnter = () => {
    if (WidthAndHeight().width > 943) {
      console.log("WidthAndHeight().width")
    }
  }

  return (
    <ul onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseEnter}>
      {
        props.Options.map((Option: IMenu, index: number) => (
          <li key={index} className={(Option.subitem && Option.subitem.length > 0) ? styles["menu-dropdown-icon"] : styles["normal-sub"]} onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseEnter}>
            <a href={Option.link}>{Option.name}</a>
            {/* Base Case */}
            {
              (Option.subitem && Option.subitem.length > 0) &&
              <MenuList Options={Option.subitem} />
            }
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Can anyone guide me on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: You should make your own custom hook for what you are trying to do. Since you are not returning anything from that class it;'s not a React component. And your React component can only be used as JSX to render something. It can't be used to solve some logic.

Comment: @AtinSingh Kindly can you help me how can I do that !!

Comment: I am very new to REact

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Comment: @Milind if you are new to React, I would suggest: Learn about [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), also get comfortable with `React.Component`, then learn about [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already created custom hook, but used it wrong. The code below should work.

```
const MenuList = (props: IMenuListProps) => {
  const { width, height } = WidthAndHeight(); // --> call hook in component function body, not in eventhandler!
  const handleOnMouseEnter = () => {
    if (width > 943) {
      //...
    }
  }

  return (
    <ul onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseEnter}>
      {
        props.Options.map((Option: IMenu, index: number) => (
          <li key={index} className={(Option.subitem && Option.subitem.length > 0) ? styles["menu-dropdown-icon"] : styles["normal-sub"]} onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseEnter}>
            <a href={Option.link}>{Option.name}</a>
            {/* Base Case */}
            {
              (Option.subitem && Option.subitem.length > 0) &&
              <MenuList Options={Option.subitem} />
            }
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom hook for what you are doing -

```
function useWidthAndHeight() {
  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(window.innerWidth);
  const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(window.innerHeight);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateWidthAndHeight);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateWidthAndHeight);
  });

  const updateWidthAndHeight = () => {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    setHeight(window.innerHeight);
  };

 const windowData =  {
      "width": width,
      "height": height
    }
  return (
   windowData
  );
}

export default function useWidthAndHeight
```

Then you can import it like this.

`import useWidthAndWIndow from "./customHook.js"`

And use it as a hook inside your functional component

`const windowData = useWidthAndWIndow()`

Comment: I guest you have to call `useWidthAndHeight ()` which will return  { windowData } and it's updates.

Comment: But he implemented the custom hook, but used it in wrong place. See my answer below.

Comment: @RafaelHovsepyan I am sorry but can a custom hook start with an uppercase letter like a react component?

Comment: @RafaelHovsepyan according to react docs it says `Do I have to name my custom Hooks starting with “use”? Please do. This convention is very important. Without it, we wouldn’t be able to automatically check for violations of rules of Hooks because we couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to Hooks inside of it.`

Comment: It's just an convention, you don't have even use "use" prefix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204195/discussion-between-rafael-hovsepyan-and-atin-singh).

Comment: The point is that you should call the `hook` inside of function component, at the very upper scope. Not in handler and functions in inner scope.

Comment: @RafaelHovsepyan yes but it's better to use the convention and even so if the React team itself has mentioned that the convention is very important.

Comment: @AtinSingh then what is the solution

Comment: @Milind see my answer

Comment: my bad I thought you were using hook inside MegaMenu component